# Overlaying multiple div pictures

Tags: css, css-position, overlay

So I am trying to make a loop of images that has description overlaying each of it. The overlay would be visible when the picture is hovered. Here is an example of the code.

```css
.container {
  height: 100px;
  width:100px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.picture {
  height: 100%;
  width:100%
}

.contAlign {
  text-align: center;
}

.desc {
  position:flex;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0%;
  opacity: 0.5;
  transition: .5s ease;
}

.container:hover .desc {
  height: 40%;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="contAlign">
  <div class="container">
    <img class="picture" src="https://kbob.github.io/images/sample-3.jpg">
    <div class="desc"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <img class="picture" src="https://imagej.nih.gov/ij/images/baboon.jpg">
    <div class="desc"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <img class="picture" src="https://www.visioncritical.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/BLG_Andrew-G.-River-Sample_09.13.12.png">
    <div class="desc"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In this case, the description box goes downwards since I wasnt using position: absolute;. However if I do so, the box wont inherit the pictures size and takes the size of the page. How do I solve this?

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/mjzfkg59/40/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the position of `container` to `relative` so the `desc`ription would be absolute in relation to it:

```css
.container {
  height: 100px;
  width:100px;
  display: inline-block;
  position:relative;
}

.picture {
  height: 100%;
  width:100%
}

.contAlign {
  text-align: center;
}

.desc {
  position:absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0%;
  opacity: 0.5;
  transition: .5s ease;
}

.container:hover .desc {
  height: 40%;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="contAlign">
  <div class="container">
    <img class="picture" src="https://kbob.github.io/images/sample-3.jpg">
    <div class="desc"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <img class="picture" src="https://imagej.nih.gov/ij/images/baboon.jpg">
    <div class="desc"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <img class="picture" src="https://www.visioncritical.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/BLG_Andrew-G.-River-Sample_09.13.12.png">
    <div class="desc"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what does the relative parent have to do with the child?

Comment: The document itself is the base for all absolute elements. When you make an element `relative`, its `absolute` children will place against it not against whole document. @Squish

Comment: I see, what if there is another relative position. Will the fist relative be overidden by the new one?

Comment: an `absolute` child take place in relation to its closest `relative` **parent**. Other relative elements outside a family have no effect on other families.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps you out. once you make an element absolute, just make sure to make its parent relative. so that it doesn't float anywhere. Now you can set positions accordingly where you want to make it appear on hover.

```css
.container {
  height: 100px;
  width:100px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.picture {
  height: 100%;
  width:100%
}

.contAlign {
  text-align: center;
}

.desc {
  position:absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0%;
  opacity: 0.5;
  transition: .5s ease;
}

.container:hover .desc {
  height: 40%;
}
```

```html
<div class="contAlign">
  <div class="container">
    <img class="picture" src="https://kbob.github.io/images/sample-3.jpg">
    <div class="desc"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <img class="picture" src="https://imagej.nih.gov/ij/images/baboon.jpg">
    <div class="desc"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <img class="picture" src="https://www.visioncritical.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/BLG_Andrew-G.-River-Sample_09.13.12.png">
    <div class="desc"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what does the relative parent do to the child? wont the absolute position of the child still overlap the parents class?

Comment: Actually relative parent defines that the absolute child  scope is limited to the area of the relative parent element.